# Mac command line oddity

Tags: macos, command-line

I have been noticing something weird when typing in commands. This is what I get when I do an `ls -la` on an empty folder:

```
sh-3.2# ls -la  
total 0  
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel   68 Apr  2 15:53 .  
drwxr-x---  16 root  wheel  544 Apr  2 15:53 ..  
-ne  
sh-3.2#
```

Why is there an `-ne` showing up after I type in a command? Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I get when I `echo $PS1`.

```
\s-
   \$
-ne
```

Gordon - This is what I get when I `printf "'%q'\n" "$PS1"`

```
'\\s-\\v\\\$\ '
-ne
```

Comment: Better ask on ServerFault or SuperUser

Comment: Show us the contents of your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files (if they exist).

Comment: The don't exist

Comment: the results you got from the echo were rather hard to parse.  Please try `printf "'%q'\n" "$PS1"` and report the results.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was is in .bash_profile.  I was given some helper commands to make bash more friendly but these helpers where not designed for a Mac.  I should have analyzed those helpers some more.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something in your prompt variable (`PS1`) could be messed up. What's you prompt set to?

```
# echo $PS1
```

Comment: I added the response to the question.  What do I need to to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at the code that's running for PS1. Check your .bashrc for any line that sets PS1, and see if there is anything that looks like `-ne`.  `-ne` is bash/ksh/sh/zsh code for 'not equal'.  You may have something being set and you forgot the closing quote.